# How to Convert Tree Structure List to Json

Tags: java, spring-boot, fancytree

I have query result like this :

| DEPT_NAME | DEPT_R_IDX | DEPT_IDX | DEPT_LEVEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| root | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| dept_0 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| dept_1 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| dept_1_0 | 3 | 4 | 2 |
| dept_1_1 | 3 | 5 | 2 |
| dept_2 | 1 | 6 | 1 |
| dept_2_0 | 6 | 7 | 2 |
| dept_2_0_1 | 7 | 8 | 3 |

- DEPT_IDX is PRIMARY KEY, DEPT_LEVEL is TREE DEPTH, DEPT_R_IDX is parent's DEPT_IDX

I stored this data in Java's List.

List<HashMap<String, String>> DEPT_LIST;

I want convert this List to Json like this :

```
[
    {
        "title": "root",
        "key": "1",
        "expanded": true,
        "folder": true,
        "children": [
            {
                "key": "2",
                "title": "dept_0",
                "expanded": true,
                "folder": true
            },
            {
                "key": "3",
                "title": "dept_1",
                "expanded": true,
                "folder": true,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "key": "4",
                        "title": "dept_1_0",
                        "expanded": true,
                        "folder": true
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "5",
                        "title": "dept_1_1",
                        "expanded": true,
                        "folder": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "key": "6",
                "title": "dept_2",
                "expanded": true,
                "folder": true,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "key": "7",
                        "title": "dept_2_0",
                        "expanded": true,
                        "folder": true,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "key": "8",
                                "title": "dept_2_1",
                                "expanded": true,
                                "folder": true
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
]
```

result tree using this json data(using [fancytree](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree))

[image: 1]

i tried this in browser side, but it's too low performance to make json structure

Comment: Usually we get POs(Persistant object) from database,  and use json frameworks like jackson return the POs to frontend, we use @JsonProperty on field of PO to customize how to format one field

Comment: I don\`t think it is a good idea that you save the data in a List<HaspMap<>>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing your data in a `List<HashMap<String, String>>`, store them in a `List<Node>` where class `Node` is something like this:

```
public class Node {
    private String title;
    private String key;
    private boolean expanded;
    private boolean folder;
    private List<Node> children;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return expanded;
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }

    public boolean isFolder() {
        return folder;
    }

    public void setFolder(boolean folder) {
        this.folder = folder;
    }

    public List<Node> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Node> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

Then use Jackson or Gson to generate the corresponding Json.